# Use surrogate key or accountno field as primary key

Tags: design, architecture, database

I am in the process of designing a simple portfolio management system for financial advisors. The central table here is an 'tb_account' table that holds the various accounts an advisor manages. I create a random unique account number and store it in the 'accountno' field in the table tb_account. The field is also the primary key for the table. Now there are other tables where more information about the account (a.k.a. portfolio) is stored. All these tables are driven by 'accountno'.

The question I have is, should I store 'accountno' only in tb_account table and create a unique index on it and use the surrogate primary key from the table, an 'id', in all the other tables?

I have images of both the designs here. Please let me know which is the route I can go? The pros and cons of both will also help. I am leaning toward the latter, as I can completely hide the 'accountno' field from all the tables, except the main tb_account table. But, will such a design be a hindrance if and when I choose to go the 'micro-services' route wherein joins across tables are discouraged or may even be impossible.

[image: The two designs, pictorially.]

Comment: Where did you see that joins across tables are discouraged?  That's literally the whole point of a relational database.

Comment: @ChrisMurray "when I choose to go the 'micro-services' route" ... I think the implication here is that these tables will be behind different microservices, hence, they should not or *cannot* be joined, because they'll actually managed by distinct applications.

Comment: That's right @svidgen. Assuming I go with the 2nd design, I may have to make a call to the 'account' service using the 'accountno' value, fetch the pk which is the 'id' and use this to fetch/update values in other services such as position, transaction, etc.

Comment: Is the account number a sensitive piece of information? If so you may want to minimize the number of places you store it and use the surrogate key instead. Back in the day, HR systems used to use social security number as the primary key... they were into a bit of a mess when the regulatory environment changed and they had to start encrypting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the second approach.  The problem with using information like account numbers as your primary key is that they can in theory change (yes, even if the client says right now they won't ever change).  Stick with the id field that uniquely identifies the database row.

Comment: Yes, @GrandmasterB, I intend to use the second approach.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that a PK should never be seen by a user, so they can never ask for it to be changed.

Comment: Sorry, after fully waking up, I find this answer to be misleading. In many business settings, if you give a customer an account number, **they should not own it**. It's an auditing key. Whatever number the customer has on their N-year-old invoice should be in your database. And, it should be guaranteed to *never change.*

Comment: @svidgen What do you mean 'misleading'?  Are you implying I'm being deceptive?  Back here on Earth account numbers change.  I've had many bank account numbers change after banks merged.  What 'should' be is irrelevant, it happens. They don't make good PK's.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Nooo ... no no no. Sorry. Not *deceptive.* It addresses a technical problem and makes implications about the business reasons behind the technical judgement. But, I think you just "missed" some business concerns. ... The systems I've worked in treat account numbers, invoice numbers, etc. *very very carefully*. In cases where the systems do permit changes, *very very strict logging/logging is required.* ... And mechanisms need to be built into the customer and/or business-facing interfaces to ensure fidelity between the digital records and the paper records.

Comment: Your bank merging example is a special case -- at least one business entity essentially disappeared. So, I'm guessing the auditing requirements are different there. But, if I were to bet on it, I'd wager your old account numbers are still in the database. I'd even wager your old *accounts* are -- with an "inactive" or "merged" status code on them or something. ... I'm not 100% sure -- since it's been at least 7 years -- but I think this is how MS Dynamics GP worked. (Thankfully, I do not work on systems even remotely related to accounting or bookkeeping anymore!)

Comment: FWIW, I looked up the [GP schema](http://dyndeveloper.com/DynModule.aspx), and it's even wackier than I remember. Each table has a pseudo-PK (acct. #, cust. #, inv. #, etc.). Records also have a unique, globally managed key, but that key is used exclusively for managing row locks (*never* for joins/FK's or *anything you might use a PK for*). ... If I'm reading/remember correctly, the raw, customer-visible account/customer/invoice numbers are used as PK's. They show on invoices/stmts, they're indexed, use for SQL joins, etc. ... It's all about auditability guarantees, AFAIK.

Comment: @svidgen special cases happen unfortunately.  I have no doubt, in the case of bank account numbers changing, that the old number is still around somewhere.  Probably in a table that maps the old numbers to the new number.  I personally always use a unique, row identifier that has no context beyond being a row id as the PK.  For public consumption (account number or something for a URL), if need be I'll add some unique public facing value (a UUID, for example) that can be used as an alternative key.

Answer (score 2):

A good PK has three properties, *at a minimum*:

- **It's unique.** (Sufficient "space" to generate new ID's.)
- **It's small.** (Unlike a `varchar` for example.)
- **It's stable and independent.** (It doesn't encode or derive from information about the record.)

There could be other requirements, depending on circumstances. For example, some database engines also benefit significantly from using **ascending PK's**, due to the fact that they order records in disk by PK (at least by default). Appending a record to the end of a table is a good deal faster than inserting at unpredictable locations.

**But there are also business considerations here.**

- Yes: Anything a customer or stakeholder sees on the screen they'll believe is *theirs*.
- But also: If account numbers are mutable, your auditing requirements can *skyrocket*.

These two things are *potentially* at odds with each other. (Though, probably not as often as you think.) And, you need to sort out which is more important to the business — how important auditability is and *how you're going to perform an audit if an account numbers are mutable.*

When a customer *or fraudster* calls with an account number, it should *always* refer to something in your database. When a customer calls with questions about a document (statement, invoice, etc.), the account number on that doc should *always* match an account in your database.

When there are rogue, unpaid orders on an account that has changed numbers, you should be able to tell the customer which account number was used to place the order. *Etc.*

And of course, when an *actual auditor* is digging through your records, **they will not be happy if the paper records don't match the digital ones!**

Now, you can certainly have separate PK's and account numbers — both unique fields. Maybe one is an ugly UUID and the other is a nice, short `char`. But, do not separate these fields under the assumption that it's a good idea to ever change *either one*. They should both be immutable. (The customer-facing account number even more-so than the PK, IMO...)

Comment: Very valid comments, @svidgen. I guess I will go with the 2nd approach. The 'accountno' stays in just one table and is not visible in other areas of the database. The join or the multiple API calls may be a bit of an overhead, but I guess I can live with that.